# Enabling/Disabling the menu item from another thread

Tags: c#

I am trying to change a menu item from another thread. I am able to use the InvokeRequired/Invoke on other controls, but since the menu item is not a Control, I am having difficulty in achieving the same functionality.

For other controls, I am doing this:

```
private delegate void SetControlEnableHandler(object sender, Boolean bValue);

private void SetControlEnabled(object sender, Boolean bValue)
{
  Control control = (Control)sender;
  if (control.InvokeRequired)
    control.Invoke(
        new SetControlEnableHandler(SetControlEnabled),
        new object[] { sender, bValue }
    );
  else
    control.Enabled = bValue;
}
```

From the worker thread I simple call:

```
this.SetControlEnabled(btnPress, true);
```

and it does the job.

Can anyone help me with the menu item here?

Thank You,
-Bhaskar

Comment: just a note, wouldn't be better if you simply notify the UI thread when your operation has completed then the UI thread will be responsible to change the control properties? This would also isolate better the background/backend/worker logic from the user interface.

Answer (score 5):

The menu item is not a control, but the Form hosting the menustrip is. So, a method in that form can modify the menuitem, if called in the correct thread.

so,

```
private void EnableMenuItem(ToolStripMenuItem item, bool enabled)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            item.Enabled = enabled;
        }
        ));
    }
```

will probably do what you want. Note the use of an anonymous method to save have to define a delegate that (probably) isn't going to be used elsewhere.

Also, as an aside, the overload of Control.Invoke that you're using has it's second argument marked with the params [] - this is how c# inplements variable numbers of arguments. You don't have to contstruct an object array, just add as many objects you need as parameters.

For example,

```
control.Invoke(new SetControlEnableHandler(SetControlEnabled), new object[] { sender, bValue } );
```

can be written as

```
control.Invoke( new SetControlEnableHandler(SetControlEnabled), sender, bValue);
```

It's much nicer, i'm sure you'll agree.